# Bash script to delete watched videos

Tags: bash, video, stat

I would like to create a bash script to check video files in a directory, and delete those, that are already watched.

I was thinking about using `stat -c %w` and `stat -c %x`  and compare the birth and the last access of the video.

I have used `stat -c %w` to determine the date of the file creation, but I am unsure of `stat -c %x`. When is the access time updated? Will it really show the last time the video was opened? Is there any other scenarios that could change the access time?

Another issue is files that are in a directory and not "naked" in the work-directory. How should I handle those?

Do you have maybe a better solution?

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better idea to use a video player that counts the times a file has been seen? With stat you cannot determine if the movie or whatever it is has been fully seen.

Comment: Yes, of this problem I am aware, but I am willing to accept it. I assume, we will finish every we video we started watching. (I am also aware how optimistic this is :))

Answer (score 0):

**find** is using `fstat` system call as well.

**-printf** option can be used to display the modification time in seconds since EPOCH (**%T@**) and access time in seconds since EPOCH (**%A@**) and filename of each files found.

Naturally, **awk** can be used to compare the values and prints only filenames with different times.

Give this a try:

```
find . -type f -printf "%T@ %A@ %p\n" | awk '{if (substr($0,1,21)!=substr($0,23,21)) { print substr($0,45); }}' | xargs -I xxxx rm 'xxxx'
```

Maybe it should be tested first with **printf**:

```
find . -type f -printf "%T@ %A@ %p\n" | awk '{if (substr($0,1,21)!=substr($0,23,21)) { print substr($0,45); }}' | xargs -I xxxx printf "%s\n" 'xxxx'
```

The test of the version with **printf**:

```
$ touch foo bar
$ ls 
bar  foo

$ find . -type f -printf "%T@ %A@ %p\n" | awk '{if (substr($0,1,21)!=substr($0,23,21)) { print substr($0,45); }}' | xargs -I xxxx printf "%s\n" 'xxxx'

$ cat foo
$ find . -type f -printf "%T@ %A@ %p\n" | awk '{if (substr($0,1,21)!=substr($0,23,21)) { print substr($0,45); }}' | xargs -I xxxx printf "%s\n" 'xxxx'
./foo
```

Note: this one-liner command is working with filenames that do not contain special chars: **\n** **"** **'** etc.